# GFCI tripped. No power beyond it

Tags: electrical

I have a tripped GFCI in my RV bathroom. There are five outlets beyond the GFCI that now have no power. This hasn’t been the issue in the past years, but now is a current issue. Any ideas?

Also, I have tried two other, brand new, GFCI’s and got the same results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you unplugged everything from the downstream outlets?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the GFCI? Have you removed all of the loads that are connected to the five outlets to see if the GFCI stays on? If it does, then try plugging each of the loads back in one at a time until the GFCI trips.

Comment: If no loads connected, the problem(mice) might be in the walls(and a PITA)

Comment: Presuming that the downstream outlets are connected to the LOAD side of the GFCI, this is exactly how it's _supposed_ to work.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is faulty, a GFCI/receptacle will only trip because something plugged into it has a ground fault or something *beyond it*, connected via the Load terminals, has a ground fault.

"Unless it is faulty" is important. Newer GFCI devices (breaker or receptacle) now have automatic self-test (because nobody actually presses the button once a month) so if something breaks inside then they will stop working. But except for outdoor GFCIs, that is relatively rare.

To troubleshoot a problem GFCI, the first step is to disconnect any wires going to the Load terminals:

- Turn off the breaker
- Pull out the GFCI/receptacle
- Remove the Load wires
- Turn on the breaker and carefully test - first the TEST/RESET buttons and then by plugging something in

If the GFCI does not work properly with nothing connected to Load then it is likely faulty and should be replaced. Small possibility it is a wiring problem, but if it used to work and now it doesn't then that will usually be the GFCI itself.

If the GFCI works properly then:

- Turn off the breaker
- Attach the Load wires
- Turn on the breaker and carefully test - first the TEST/RESET buttons and then by plugging something in

If it doesn't work any more then the problem is somewhere in the Load-connected devices. If you have 5 receptacles then you need to check every one of them. The best thing to do is to disconnect each one in sequence, but sometimes the sequence is hard to figure out.

There is a tiny possibility that a problem on the Load side is not in a receptacle but rather in the wiring - e.g., worn insulation somewhere causing enough of a problem to trip the GFCI but not enough to trip the breaker. But far more likely is a faulty receptacle, particularly if any of the receptacles are outside where they are subject to rain, wind, leaves, bugs, etc.